# Mutter and Intel GMA 4500MHD

Tags: debian, gnome, window-manager, graphics, intel-gma

I am trying to use Mutter with my Intel GMA 4500MHD (on my Thinkpad T400) in Debian Wheezy. However, it says:

> Not using GLX TFP

and some effects get very slow.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

possibly one way is to upgrade to mutter 3.0

To do this, you first have to add debian experimental repositories. Open /etc/apt/sources.list as su and add

```
# Experimental (just when explicitly demanded)
deb http://ftp.at.debian.org/debian/ experimental main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.at.debian.org/debian/ experimental main contrib non-free
```

The next step is very important. Open /etc/apt/apt.conf as su and make sure it contains this line

```
APT::Default-Release "<your release>"; # (your release could be "testing" for example)
```

If you miss this step, your system would probably change to debian experimental.

Now update your repository information

```
apt-get update
```

and install mutter from experimental

```
apt-get -t experimental install mutter
```

On my notebook the experimental mutter didn't cause any problems until now...

Maybe you would also like to read section 3.8 of [this document](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/apt-howto/ch-apt-get.en.html) before you make delicate changes on your system.

Comment: That version is now available in Debian Unstable. Can you update?

Comment: Can you explain this confusing statement, *On my notebook the experimental mutter didn't cause any problems until now...*.

Comment: oh, just wanted to say that I haven't encountered any problems (now I have problems again, but at this time everything was alright!